How to filter documents in Elasticsearch where the name field of the first element of an array is in a given list?
I am working with Elasticsearch and need to filter documents based on the value of a field in the first element of an array. Specifically, I have an array field called Tickers, and I want to check if the name field of the first element in this array matches any value from a provided list.
Here’s an example of the document structure:
{
  "Tickers": [
    {
      "name": "AAPL",
      "description": "description 0"
    },
    {
      "name": "GOOG",
      "description": "description 1"
    }
  ]
}

I need to filter documents where the name of the first element in the Tickers array is in a given list of ticker names (e.g., ["AAPL", "MSFT", "TSLA"]).
Here are my elasticsearch index mappings for Tickers Field:
{
   "Tickers":{
      "properties":{
      "name":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            }
         },
         "description":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "keyword":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            }
         }
         
      }
   }
}


What I've Tried
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "script": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "doc['Tickers.name.keyword'].length > 0 && params.symbols.contains(doc['Tickers.name.keyword'].value)",
                            "params": {"symbols": ["TSLA"]}
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


What issue are facing with this ? It seems like this query must work.

For elasticsearch version 8.16, it works well

Yea, it works. Not sure why it wasn't working yesterday. Tried different solutions.

You could unscript the search query in the following way
Mapping with copy of the name field into a new field with the limit filter
PUT /first_ticker_searching
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "whitespace_limit_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "limit_filter"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "limit_filter": {
                    "type": "limit"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "Tickers": {
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "copy_to": "first_ticker",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "first_ticker": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "whitespace_limit_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}

Your and my sample documents
PUT /first_ticker_searching/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"Tickers":[{"name":"AAPL","description":"description 0"},{"name":"GOOG","description":"description 1"}]}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"Tickers":[{"name":"APLA","description":"description 0"},{"name":"AAPL","description":"description 1"}]}

Search span_first query
GET /first_ticker_searching/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "span_first": {
                        "match": {
                            "span_term": {
                                "first_ticker": "AAPL"
                            }
                        },
                        "end": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Response. The first document is in the hits, the second one isn't
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "first_ticker_searching",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 0.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "Tickers" : [
                        {
                            "name" : "AAPL",
                            "description" : "description 0"
                        },
                        {
                            "name" : "GOOG",
                            "description" : "description 1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

